# Обрыв SSH соединение после 5 минут простоя

Tags: linux, cmd, ssh, git-bash, git-cmd

Соединение постоянно рвётся после 5 минут простоя:

- подключаюсь к своему серверу по SSH
- иду в гугл искать команду, например, для поиска файла
- возвращаюсь, а окно `git bash` не отвечает
- перезапускаю его
- ввожу заново пароль...

Это крайне раздражает! Почему так и что с этим делать?

Comment: Может это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/q/25084288/5441700

Comment: Поставьте галочку напротив `keep alive`.

Comment: Обычно sshd (или маршрутизаторы тоже) закрывает неактивные соединения. Поробуйте уговорить клиента всё время посылать я-живой. В ~/.ssh/config" добавте:
`Host *
ServerAliveInterval 120`

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло) Напишите кто-нибудь в ответ)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Обычно `sshd` сервер закрывает неактивные соединения. Часто сталкивался, что маршрутизаторы также обрывают соединения, которые какое-то время "молчат".

Можно уговорить клиента всё время посылать я-живой сигнал. 
В `~/.ssh/config` надо добавить (в секундах):

```
Host * 
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

Если файла ешё нет, надо создать и во избежание ошибки

> Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config

не забыть изменить права на запись (в некоторых версиях также и на чтение):

```
chmod go-rw ~/.ssh/config
# или
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Без конфигурации можно попробовать: `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=120 iam@my.home.ru`

Подробнее [man 5 ssh_config](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config)

В PuTTY это устанавливается в меню - Connection>Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off).

Answer (score 4):

В качестве быстрого решения можно использовать ключик в командной строке:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 user@some.host.com
```